# CakePHP 3 delete particular associated data

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Is there any way to remove some particular associated data in Cake 3?

For example in a blog example I want to remove the tag "important" from post 3?

Comment: You can delete anything you want, all you need is the appropriate condition. You may want to rephrase your question and explain the actual problem that you are facing.

Comment: @ndm The actual sceniario is this. I have a blog post and it has 5 tags. If the user licks on a tag I want to remove it from the post via an ajax call. I send the post's id and the skill's id to the controller. One idea is to get the post, loop the tags, remove the the selected one, and save the post. The other idea is to remove the matching record from the join model directly. I am looking for a direct way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the the methods in the association class to remove the link between one entity and the other:

```
$post = ... // Fetch the post that contains the tag
$tag = $this->Posts->Tags->get($this->request->data('tag_to_delete'));
$this->Posts->Tags->unlink($post, [$tag]);
```